# Import JS file inside node_modules in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular app, to this I am trying to add an npm package called svgedit. It gets installed. But when I try to reference a java-script file it says

> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

This is how I am trying to reference it in my index.html in the head section,

```
<script type="module" src="node_modules/svgedit/svgedit-config-es.js"></script>
```

I can access this file from within vs code by clicking "ctrl + left mouse". It opens the file properly meaning the reference is proper. But when it runs it gives the above mentioned error in the console. I have also tried switching the type attribute to "text/javascript".

Basically I am trying to integrate this package in my angular app. What is the correct method to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

`ng serve` will only serve compiled files from your `src` directory and what''s in the `assets` folder.  It will not serve `node_module` files directly.

The usual way to add scripts it to add it to the `scripts` section in `angular.json`

```
scripts: 
 [ //other scripts
   "node_modules/svgedit/svgedit-config-es.js"
 ]
```

Comment: I had tried that too but in that case it gives an error saying.."cannot import statement outside a module" inside the scripts.js file where the js file imports another dependent js file within it. does that mean all the dependent scripts will have to be added to the scripts section? Kindly direct how to go about this, I am just starting off so please bear with me.

Comment: Is there a way to combine all the dependent files in the external application and add it to the assets folder may be? and then add script tags to the index.html referencing the resources from the asset folder?.

Answer (score -1):

Is your html page in the root directory of your project? if not make sure to navigate to the file correctly. if the html page in the root directory of your project then there must be a typo in the src

Comment: like i said the file is opening up when I click the link in the html from within vs code. this means the reference path is correct right? The index file is in the app folder of the angular directory structure.

Answer (score -1):

> Basically I am trying to integrate this package in my angular app. What is the correct method to go about it.

The right way to go about it is to use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) etc...

Comment: the npm package that I am using for svg edit uses rollup already. This is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgedit/v/3.0.0-alpha.4. I also ran npm install from within the folder of the package (node_modules/svgedit)